# Overloading comparison operators for different types in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, comparison-operators

I need to be able to compare one of my classes (which contains a lot more than an integer) to integers, even though that might be stretching the like of equality a little it's close enough...

**How do I overload the equality operator for different types?**

I basically have a class like this

```
struct MyClass {
    int start;
    int middle;
    int threequarters;
};
```

and the overloaded operator

```
inline bool operator==(const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs) {
    return lhs.middle == rhs.middle;
}
```

So when comparing with integers I need to compare against the middle variable as well, but I'm not sure if I need two sets of operator functions, one where integer is lhs and one where integer is rhs?

```
inline bool operator==(const int& lhs, const MyClass& rhs) {
    return lhs == rhs.middle;
}

inline bool operator==(const MyClass& lhs, const int& rhs) {
    return lhs.middle == rhs;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you should do it that way - support (int,MyClass) and (MyClass,int). Although you can define one of the operators in terms of the other. Another possibility is to have a constructor for MyClass which constructs from an int - then you'll only need an operator(MyClass,MyClass) because when the compiler encounters the int it can promote it to be type MyClass for the operator.

Comment: So to compare MyClass with MyClass, and integers with MyClass, I'll need 3 sets of every comparison function (18 in total), even though most of them will reference others..?

Comment: Or give your class a converting constructor `MyClass(int i) : middle(i) {}`.

Comment: Overloading the comparison operator so that it doesn't compare all parts of the object seems like bad practice to me. If you want a function like this I would prefer to just define a function with a name that describes what it does, something like `bool areEqualAtMiddle(const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs)`

Comment: @ChrisDrew Yes I know, it's just that I store these `MyClass` in a set and at some points during the execution I only have access to the middle value, so I need to get the reference back somehow...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To clarify from my comment, this will support code so you can either provide all variations of operators:

```
inline bool operator==(const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs) {
return lhs.middle == rhs.middle;
}

inline bool operator==(const int& lhs, const MyClass& rhs) {
return lhs == rhs.middle;
}

inline bool operator==(const MyClass& lhs, const int& rhs) {
return lhs.middle == rhs;
}
```

And do that for every operator (which blows up into a significant amount of code). OR if it makes sense to, you can provide a constructor which constructs from int:

```
struct MyClass {
MyClass() {} // default
MyClass( int x ) { /* init for an int here */ }
int start;
int middle;
int threequarters;
};
```

If you do this, then you will only need the MyClass,MyClass version for each operator:

```
inline bool operator==(const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs) {
return lhs.middle == rhs.middle;
}
```

Because when the compiler sees:

```
if ( 5 == my_class ) {}
```

It actually does this:

```
if ( MyClass(5).operator==( my_class ) ) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to define three operator == provided that your class has no conversion constructor for objects of type int.

```
inline bool operator==(const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs) {
    return lhs.middle == rhs.middle;
}

inline bool operator==(const MyClass& lhs, int rhs) {
    return lhs.middle == rhs;
}

inline bool operator==(int lhs, const MyClass& rhs) {
    return operator ==( rhs, lhs );
}
```

Comment: And I shouldn't ... const int& rhs ...?

Comment: @user3235200 No there is no any need to use const int &. it is enough and better to use int.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need both operators.

```
bool operator==(const A& a, const int & b)
{
    return a.value == b;
};
```

With only the above operator defined, the compiler will throw an error that no conversion is available if you try the following: `2 == a` (considering that the class A has no implicit constructors that take an integer as an argument)

For each binary operation, the compiler tries to do an implicit conversion to fit the operation. For instance, if `class A` had an `operator int` definition, you would not need the operators, since the compiler would implicitly convert the `A` type to an integer and then perform the `bool operator==(int,int)` operation. If no operator is defined, then the compiler throws an error, saying that there is no conversion available (i.e, no operator == that accepts A as an argument on either left or right side)